# Is this a Valid ID?

Tags: javascript, html, spiceworks

I have this code and I would like to know how to set id values to `<h4>` and know if the id is valid.

```
 container.insert({ bottom: '<h4 style="margin:8px 0px 4px 0px; padding-left:0px ; select id=comment_'+ l +'">' + l + '</h4>' });
```

I need this so I can hide/show this `<h4>` depending on the value of a combo box.

Or is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: You might want to see this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html

Comment: you can give an id to whatever you want, but not inside a `style` definition. The " before the > should be after the `0px ;`... and what is a 'select' inside an h4 definition?

Comment: i dint saw the select in there ^^ can u post how the code should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attributes on the H4 appear to be malformed explaining why you cant navigate the to the h4 by an id selector

```
<h4 style="margin:8px 0px 4px 0px; padding-left:0px ; select id=comment_'+ l +'">
```

Should be

```
<h4 style="margin:8px 0px 4px 0px; padding-left:0px;" id="comment_'+ l +'">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give an id attribute to any elements you like, even script/link/head and other tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an ID to any element you like. As for its validity:

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Comment: but when i try to the the element by id i dont get nothing